# In cocoa2.0 does @property obviate variable declaration in the interface

Tags: cocoa

Just experimenting with @property and @synthesize:

```
@interface Greeter : NSObject 
//{
//  NSString * name;
//}
@property (assign) NSString * name;
- (NSString *) greeting;
@end
```

It seems to be the case that if you declare a variable using @property that you don't have to declare it between the braces (and you don't even need the braces if all of your interface variables are all declared using @property). Is this always correct?  And is it good style to leave out the top part of the interface (braces included)?  I have been using both and been irritated by the redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

There is no “Cocoa 2.0”.

In Objective-C 2.0, on [the modern runtime](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH106), yes, you can leave out the instance variables, and the property will generate them for you. [The legacy runtime](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH106) on Mac OS X still requires explicit instance variables.

You cannot leave out the ivar section entirely *yet*, but you can leave it empty.

Comment: What are the best practices for this?  Leave it out to make it clean, or keep them in for explicity's sake?

Comment: @Jess Bowers: I currently leave them in so as to refer to them from `init` and `dealloc`, but will start leaving them out after Clang 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the webpage where I first found out you can automatically have you properties synthesized and also declare new properties in class extensions. It gives a bit of interesting back story as well.

http://www.mcubedsw.com/blog/index.php/site/comments/new_objective-c_features/

As for style and correctness, I've been using primarily properties for the last couple of weeks and it has made my code look quite clean! I can now declare private properties in my implementation and not have them exposed in the header making any interface to use my classes very simple and non-confusing to use.

I've ran into a problem when using interface builder where having an iVar to any subviews of a view controller still has to be declared in the header for interface builder to see it as an IBOutlet and assign to it. You can still declare those @private though and then have the private properties declared in a class extension in your implementation if you really want it as a property for you to use.

```
// In your header
@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController {
    @private
    IBOutlet UIButton *buttonPeopleShouldNotKnowAbout;  
}
@end

// And in your implementation
@implementation MenuViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonPeopleShouldNotKnowAbout;
@end
```